# Upload to youtube and keep all mp4 settings

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, mp4

Is it possible to create an mp4 in such a way that youtube will more or less leave it alone when uploaded? I.E. I want to upload a file to youtube, and then re-download it later using a firefox plugin for saving streams to mp4, and have the files contain the same mdat data that is in the original mp4?

This may be wishful thinking, but I was just wondering if you have a very particular set of settings for framerate, resolution, samples, bitrate, etc, if it is possible to upload to youtube and keep all of those intact.

Comment: Off-topic. Websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress are off topic, See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

No. Youtube re-encodes all uploaded files.

My guess is, they do so, in order to make sure all served media conforms to a narrow set of standards. There's probably a security concern too, of someone using Youtube to distribute a steganographic payload. Re-encoding avoids that scenario.

Comment: Some enterprise customers like VEVO probably get to generate the final streams themselves, judging by stream quality.